# How to see network traffic per interface in FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, ifconfig

want to see an amount of traffic passed through interface since boot. It's an ISPManager VDS with FreeBSD 8.0, and

```
ifconfig -L epair521b -B
```

does nothing.

Want to have output like Linux's ifconfig:

> lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
>   ...
>
> RX bytes:6642443661 (6.1 GiB)  TX bytes:6642443661 (6.1 GiB)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
systat -ifstat 1
```

Is much better.  You gonna get traffic throughput, Peak and Total.

Comment: Nice - I haven't used this command for 12 years I was thinking it was netstat

Answer (score 7):

Reading file `/usr/local/share/munin/plugins/if_` (in port `sysutils/munin-node`) I see it's using the following command line to achieve just that :

```
/usr/bin/netstat -i -b -n -I $INTERFACE
```

PS: that file also contains a warning that those are 32 bit counters; some years ago I RTFS and verifier that's because it's easier to update atomically; I didn't verify if it's the same on the (more recent) amd64 platform though.

Comment: This is perfect for me, as I needed a command with static output so I could use it in a script.